# How to generate a unique long (hash) for an object of arbitrary type?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, hash

My goal is to create a method with the following requirements:

- Output should be consistent across different app domains (but which are running the same version of the .Net framework)
- Objects of different types should not generate the same hash
- Collisions are extremely unlikely
- The method will be called fairly frequently, so should not be too slow

The implementations that I'm considering look something like:

```
private static long GenerateHash<TKey>(TKey key)
{
    long typeHash = typeof(TKey).GetHashCode();
    long keyHash = key.GetHashCode();
    return (typeHash << 32) + keyHash;
}
```

and

```
private static long GenerateHash<TKey>(TKey key)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); // Or other serialiser
            formatter.Serialize(stream, key);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var hashAlgorithm = new SuitableHashAlgorithm(); // Not real class, need to find/write a hash algorithm that can compute 64 bit hashes...
            var hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(stream);
            return BitConverter.ToInt64(hash, 0);
        }
}
```

Note, the possible nullness of key is not a consideration.

Any comments and potential pitfalls of these implementations welcomed along with any other possible ones.

Thanks

Comment: Regular `GetHashCode()` is not guaranteed between app-domains, and `BinaryFormatter` is not *EVER* guaranteed to produce the same results (there  were some counter-examples here on SO recently, where the same data could produce different outputs) - it is only intended to get your data back intact, not provide a consistent data layout.

Comment: Do you want something generic that can be used on any object? I assume reflection would be too heavyweight for what you want.

Comment: I think you better have a look at this post [Guidelines for HashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx)

Comment: @V4Vendetta from the question, it sounds like the OP is aware of the considerations there

Comment: @MarcGravell Maybe ! but his first point made me look up for this post unless i misunderstood something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the requirements cannot be met with the stated method signature, thanks all for your comments, particularly @Marc Gravell.

I'll introduce a suitable interface with a UniqueId property which all keys will implement.

I was hoping to avoid this in order to maintain backwards compatibility, but hey ho, you can't always get what you want!